# Sending data with kafka-python only working when briefly delaying code

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-kafka

I'm sending some data to a Kafka topic using kafka-python. I struggled with not being able to send data to my Kafka topic for a while until I found out that if I delay the code briefly it works.

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from time import sleep

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092")
producer.send("topic", "foo")
sleep(.1)
```

This code **does not** work for me without using `sleep(.1)`. It's like sending data needs time to settle for it to work properly. Is there anything in the kafka-python client that deals with this? Or a better solution?

Comment: There a multiple Kafka Python clients available. Which one do you use? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients#Clients-Python

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax http://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python

Comment: @vesche Were you able to figure out this mystery? Why it needs to sleep for the message to show up on Kafka? I went through the same struggle till I came across this post. And then tried, sleep(.1) and it worked! I am more annoyed than relieved as to why this made it work. Please do share any info that you may have found related to this.

Comment: @activelearner I ended up finding out that if you send single entries like this it won't work without some sort of delay. However, if you loop through something and send many entires that you don't need the delay. In the end, I had so many problems with kafka that I ended up using a different MQ system.

Comment: There is a `producer.flush(timeout=10)` and `producer.close(timeout=10)` but that did not worked for me in `kafka-python==2.0.2`. I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 8):

A year later, but to anyone seeing this, a solution is below.  The issue here is race condition with the end of the script and the send call, which is why the sleep() command works.

The kafka module should better handle the python exit, or at the minimum output something to standard out/error, so this behavior isn't silent.

From the kafka-python github:

```
# Block until a single message is sent (or timeout)
future = producer.send('foobar', b'another_message')
result = future.get(timeout=60)
```

Now you can guarantee that your script will block until a message has been confirmed published.